# How to configure prescaler and interrupt for the Timer used in the capture function of the ESP32's MCPWM module?

Tags: esp32, capture, arduino-esp32

I am working on a project where every 50ms I need to send a 15us pulse from a microcontroller port, to discharge a capacitor. During the counting of these 50ms, this capacitor is charged again, producing a sawtooth wave. Then, its output is connected to a comparator circuit, which in turn has its output connected to another port of the microcontroller. Thus, when detecting a falling edge on this port, the microcontroller must use a capture peripheral to get the value of the timer count.

This is used for 16-bit AD conversion of signals, and works well on PIC microcontrollers, however, I need to replace the PIC with an ESP32. To accomplish this task, I tried to use the capture function of the MCPWM module, but I cannot change the clock speed of the timer (which is 80Mhz) to overflow in 50ms, and I cannot set an overflow interrupt on this timer to send the 15us pulse to discharge the capacitor.

Is there a way of doing that using this microcontroller?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true);` will provide a clock divider of 80 to divide the peripheral clock down to 1MHz (that is, 1uS) with a count-up counter, you can then do `timerAlarmWrite(timer, 50000, true);` for counter to count up to 50000 to generate an interrupt with every 50mS. Check the ESP32 timer library examples.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! So far, I just tried: **mcpwm_gpio_init(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM0A, GPIO_CAP0_IN);**  and **mcpwm_capture_enable(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM_SELECT_CAP0, MCPWM_NEG_EDGE, 0);**, but I did not know a way to set the 50ms period. Does this function "timerAlarmWrite" use the same timer as the " mcpwm_capture" function?

Comment: Sorry, you tag `arduino-esp32`, so I assumed that you are using Arduino Framework, but it seems that you are using ESP-IDF, you should tag `esp-idf`. Fo using the time with esp-idf, please read [timer](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.2/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/timer.html) section of ESP-IDF programming guide.

Comment: I'm actually using Arduino IDE and the project compiles without errors with the codes I mentioned above. I'm providing a circuit to perform a physical test implementing this "timerAlarmWrite" function.